# SimpleXML giving an Uncaught Error in Webserver despite it being installed and enabled in CLI

Tags: php, gcloud, simplexml

I'm trying to run a php script on a lamp server in google cloud.  The script is failing because of an uncaught error, despite SimpleXML and xml being installed and active (as far as I can tell).  Having just moved to Google Cloud, I'm not familiar enough with the environment, and don't know if I'm missing some basic setup steps.  I have wordpress running set up and running successfully on the same server, so I'm a bit baffled by this.  Would appreciate any help or direction!

PHP 8.2.8 on Ubuntu 20.04.6 LTS.

I'm getting this error whenever I try to use SimpleXMLElement.

```
Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class "SimpleXMLElement" not found in /var/www/html/ifg_indexp/tpnapis/simplexmltest.php:48
```

I thought maybe the function was not installed/enabled, but it seems to be :

```
$ php -m | grep SimpleXML
SimpleXML

$ php -m | grep xml
libxml
xml
xmlreader
xmlrpc
xmlwriter
```

php -i returns that the module is enabled, so that seems ok too.

```
$ php -i

SimpleXML
SimpleXML support => enabled
Schema support => enabled
```

Also xml is showing as active :

```
 
xml
XML Support => active
XML Namespace Support => active
libxml2 Version => 2.9.14
```

The simplified file I'm trying to test with is as follows :

```
<?php

use SimpleXMLElement;
//use SimpleXML;
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);

$note = <<<XML
    <depots>
        <depot>
            <number>001</number>
            <phone>111</phone>
            <name>company1</name>
            <depotaddress>
                <add1>address line1</add1>
                <add2>address 2</add2>
            </depotaddress>
        </depot>
        <depot>
            <number>002</number>
            <phone>222</phone>
            <name>company2</name>
            <depotaddress>
                <add1>address1</add1>
                <add2>address2</add2>
            </depotaddress>
        </depot>
    </depots>
XML;

echo "</br>printf : ";printf($note);
echo "</br>var_dump : ";var_dump($note);
echo "</br>asXML :";

$xml = new SimpleXMLElement($note);
echo $xml;
echo $xml->asXML();

?>
```

That gives me this result on screen :

```
printf : 001 111 company1 address line1 address 2 002 222 company2 address1 address2
var_dump : string(364) " 001 111 company1 address line1 address 2 002 222 company2 address1 address2 "
asXML :
Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class "SimpleXMLElement" not found in /var/www/html/xxx1/xxx2/simplexmltest.php:40 Stack trace: #0 {main} thrown in /var/www/html/xxx1/xxx2/simplexmltest.php on line 40
```

The only other things that seem odd to me is that the PHP version on phpinfo() is different to the version on cli.
Also, there is no SimpleXML details box on the phpinfo() screen.

Comment: You've checked that the module is available on the CLI, but if you are using this on the web, you should also create a page with `phpinfo();` on it to make sure it is available there, too.

Comment: Ah now reading it, the php configuration on the command-line can be totally unrelated to the one of Wordpress even if they are on the same server. Enable SimpleXML in the PHP of Wordpress, the error message just shows you didn't yet. There are pretty many duplicate Q&As of that as you might imagine.

Comment: @hakre - Thanks, yes. I did check phpinfo, as Chris suggested, but while SimpleXML is credited down the bottom on the phpinfo page, I can't see a section box anywhere on the page saying that SimpleXML or XML is enabled.  

The configuration file php.ini path is /etc/php/8.0/apache2/php.ini
So I edited that file and added the extension lines : 
;extension=SimpleXML
;extension=xml

But it doesn't seem to have made any difference despite rebooting and restarting the server and apache.

Comment: The section headline is "SimpleXML" and the table cell is "SimpleXML support", the cell next to it has "enabled" if you enabled it. If that is missing, enable the extension. If you already did, check the PHP error log for startup errors what the reason is why the extension could not be loaded, e.g. it was not installed. If it was not properly installed, install it. Then enable it. Then reload the webserver and/or the PHP process manager (if you use one) and you will see it enabled. Document your work, review the changes of your provision scripts, commit the configuration change and push.